# ImportError with SeqIO from Biopython in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder, bioinformatics, biopython

By writting this post I hope to be able to solve the problem that is driving me crazy!

I am trying to use Biopython using Spyder as IDE. I have installed Biopython in Linux Mint by using conda and also I have installed using pip. Everything seems okay, I tried in the terminal and in Spyder and it works. However, when I try to use the next order:

`from Bio import SeqIO`

Spyder terminal gives me the next answer:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-2-5d24a7c49c42>", line 1, in <module>
    from Bio import SeqIO
  File "/home/andrea/Descargas/biopython-1.74/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py", line 387, in <module>
    from Bio.Align import MultipleSeqAlignment
  File "/home/andrea/Descargas/biopython-1.74/Bio/Align/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from Bio.Align import _aligners
ImportError: cannot import name '_aligners' from 'Bio.Align' (/home/andrea/Descargas/biopython-1.74/Bio/Align/__init__.py)*
```

I checked if in the terminal if this works and exactly, the terminal doesn't give me any error message. I checked if Python's version is the problem, but the terminal and Spyder are working in the same Python's version (3.7). I have also checked with other entries such as:

`from Bio import Entrez`

and it works in Spyder and in the terminal

Does anybody know what is happening here?

Thank you a lot!! :)

Comment: Thank you!! I have uninstalled both Biopython and, as you said, I installed again using pip. However Spyder gave me another error message: `Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-5d24a7c49c42>", line 1, in <module>
    from Bio import SeqIO

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio'.`                                           Do I need to do something in Spyder after I have installed Biopython using the via pip?

Comment: You should also check with your python version and install biopython accordingly, for example if you are using Python3 (eg 3.7) in Linux, remember to install biopython package with pip3 (pip3 install biopython) and for Python 2.7 (pip install biopython) @andreammo

Comment: Are you working on a virtualenv or plain python ?